# Insert directive in another directive by scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I have one directive that is an date picker, and another directive that is an bootstrap panel.

I need configure the panel directive to show an custom title and a custom content, and the content need be the date picker directive OR another directive.

I'm trying do this, but dosen't works:

html:

```
panel(title="Date", content='date-picker(ng-model="date")')
```

panel directive html:

```
.col-md-12(style="padding: 0")
   .panel.panel-default
     .panel-heading
      h1.panel-title {{ title }}
    .panel-body
      {{content}}
```

panel directive js:

```
.directive("panel", function() {
    return {
       restrict: "E",
       templateUrl: "panel.html",
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, $eval) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;
        scope.content = eval(attrs.content);
       }
     };
  })
```

UPDATE:
Now I have another issue:

I have one directive with toggle components on the view.
The configuration of toggle component is very simple:

```
input(type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle")
```

The directive works fine, but if this directive is loaded inside another directive (transclude) the toggle component do not work anymore. :(

Can you guys help me?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `transclude` option of the directive, which lets you wrap other content easily.

html: add the date-picker html within the panel element

```
panel(title="Date")
  date-picker(ng-model="date")
```

panel directive html: add `ng-transclude` to the .panel-body

```
.col-md-12(style="padding: 0")
   .panel.panel-default
     .panel-heading
      h1.panel-title {{ title }}
    .panel-body(ng-transclude)
```

panel directive js: set `transclude` to true.

```
.directive("panel", function() {
    return {
       restrict: "E",
       templateUrl: "panel.html",
       transclude: true,
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;
       }
     };
  })
```

Comment: Amazing! Works very well. Thank you Anid Monsur. :)